# GData / YouTube Interface (XCode/ObjectiveC) - Uploading a File and Obtaining the Uploaded URL or videoID

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdata

I've been working with the YouTubeTest example a bit to fully understand the GData / YouTube interface and how it uploads files to YouTube.

I've managed to get this to work on my device quite easily but one of the things I wanted to be able to do in my app was, upon completion of the upload, is share the URL of the video I just uploaded to youtube.

URL's are normally of the form :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRzVPfFIXtY

Would anyone be able to tell me how to find out what the uploaded URL would be or the videoID, as the videoID seems (I think) to be part of the URL (e.g. HRzVPfFIXtY).

Any tips or sample code greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 0):

When your file gets uploaded , function called is below

```
- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
   finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
               error:(NSError *)error

if (error == nil) {
        // tell the user that the add worked
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploaded!"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ succesfully uploaded", 
                                                                 [[videoEntry title] stringValue]]                    
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

here `VideoEntry` is `GDataEntryYoutubeVideo` type which contains all information about the uploaded video.

I get the url by separating the string.